# How to plot multiple grids of plots dynamically in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The code below allows the user to change the number of plots that are displayed. If the user selects 2 from the sliderInput 8 plots appear in a column.  I would like to display the 8  plots in 2 grids that are both 2x2. If the user selects 3 from the slider Input there will be 12 plots displayed in 3 grids that are all 2x2.

So you can see in the code below that currently 8 plots are generated and have tags and you see those tags printed in the lines below in the server.r file:

```
print(plot_output_list)
do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
```

a tag looks like:

```
<div id="plot5" class="shiny-plot-output" style="width: 400px ; height: 280px"></div>
```

After these tags are generated the renderPlot function is used to assign a plot to them in a loop. Here is the line of code

```
output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({ ......
```

THis produces 8 plots in  a column but I would like to have two  2x2 grids.

My questions are:

(1) I need to set up grids to display the 4 plots so I was going to use: par(mfrow=c(2,2)) but where should I place that code.

(2) Currently there are 8 tags generated. Should there only be 2 tags generated because there are only 2 grids?

(3) How should renderPlot be used here?  Currently RenderPlot is run 8 times and produces 8 plots but shoudl it only be run through the loop 2 times because there are only 2 grids?

Not this: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/
but the "grid" package is not available in R version 3.1.2

Here is the code which you can run with this code:

```
install.packages("shiny")
library(rJava
runApp("C://Users/me/folderTOProject")
```

Server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  max_plots<- reactive({
   print("IN reactive function")
   NumberOfPlots(input$n)
  })



  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    #plot_output_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
    print("in render UI")
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:max_plots(), function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 400)
    })
    print(plot_output_list)
    # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
    # to display properly.
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  }) #end of output$plots



  # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
  # are visible on the web page.

  observe({
            for (i in 1:max_plots()) {
            #  for (i in seq(1, maxplots(), by=4)) { #use this to only loop twice
             #   par(mfrow=c(2,2)) #SET UP THE GRID to hold 4 plots..Should this be here?

              # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
              # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
              # of when the expression is evaluated.
              local({
                my_i <- i
                plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")

                output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({

                  data<- as.data.frame(c(1,2,3))
                  plot(1:my_i, 1:my_i,
                       xlim = c(1, max_plots()),
                       ylim = c(1, max_plots()),
                       main = paste("1:", my_i, ".  max plots is ", max_plots(), sep = "")
                  )
                })#end of renderPlot
              })#end of local
            }#end of loop over max_plots
  })


  })#end of server
```

ui.r

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("tst"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=2, min=1, max=7),
    width = 2
  ),
  mainPanel(
    # This is the dynamic UI for the plots
    uiOutput("plots")

  )
))
```

global.r

```
NumberOfPlots<-function(n)
{
  print("in global") 
  print(n)
  length(seq(from=1 , to=n*4, by = 1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do either 8 separate plotOutputs, using [bootstrap rows and columns](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) to lay them out; or the two plotOutputs each with a 2x2 grid would work fine as well. The grid package is not on CRAN but is included with R itself.